# Creating conditional Value Lists for many to many relationship in filemaker

Tags: relationship, filemaker

I am creating an app for student management. My database has three tables that manage student classes; Class and Stream. These two tables have a many to many relationship so I created a third table Class Stream to join them by using their IDs.

Currently, creating conditional value lists works fine for a one to many relationship where only two tables are involved.

Now I need to create conditional value lists with three tables (Class, Stream, & Class Stream) involved whereby if I select a given class, only stream values belonging to that specific class display in form of a drop down list in the field below.

[image: table schema]

My value lists filter has two dropdown lists. The first one displays class names and the second one displays stream names. I need to make sure that when I select a class, the dropdown list for stream names contains only streams that belong to the selected class above.

[image: dropdowns]

Answer (score 1):

For create a conditional value lists, you should use a separate occurrences from original table occurrence and create a relation like this:
[Database Relations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRqW6.jpg)
and use a simple value list for Class names like this:
[Value list for class names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u88DB.jpg)
and a related value list for stream names like this:
[Value list for stream names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOg8D.jpg)